# How to pass data to a previous ViewController in Swift (Cocoa Application)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, viewcontroller

Passing data to the next viewController is simple and straightforward, and can be done using `prepareSegue` method. However, I can't understand how to pass data to a previous viewController in Swift(Cocoa Application)

I have a textfield in `viewControllerB` and when you type something in it and press a button, I want to pass it to a label in `viewControllerA` and instead of opening the viewControllerA in a new window, I just want the `viewController B` to be dismissed and the passed data to be visible on the `viewControllerA`.

That's all there is to it. I have been stuck on it for the past 48 hours. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you trying with  protocol/delegate?

Comment: We can use seque unwind too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using delegates. Example:

```
protocol NextProtocol: class {
    func sendBack(value: Int)
}

class Previous: NextProtocol {
    func sendBack(value: Int) {
        print("I have received \(value)")
    }

    func prepareSegue(...) {
        // get next instance
        var next: Next
        next.delegate = self
    }
}

class Next {
   weak var delegate: NextProtocol?

   func someMethod() {
       delegate?.sendBack(5)
   }  
}
```

Comment: Just a confusion, why are using 'prepareSegue' func in the firstViewController class?

Comment: @O.Naeem The same you pass data forward, you forward who you want receiving the data. I mentioned prepareSegue because you said that you forward the data there.